# Book about a guy that gets sent to a magical place because of an experiment, becomes a wizard

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, wizards, teleportation

I'm trying to remember the name of a book series where a guy was broke and signed up to be the guinea pig in an experiment that sent him to a magical land where he ended up being a wizard, an "aa" wizard.

I don't remember much else about it other than he was terrible at being a wizard but automatically was one because he was from somewhere else I guess? And all the other wizards were like "omg peasant, I can't believe I have to deal with you not knowing all this magic stuff already." He spent most of the book trying to get home to his wife.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you possibly clarify what you mean by an 'aa' wizard?

Comment: Ugh, I can't remember the title, but I've a feeling this is from a series called "the dragon and the george" or something...

Comment: Sounds ***a little*** like *The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant* (but not much).

Answer (score 4):

It was from the [*Dragon Knight* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Knight) by Gordon R. Dickson, one of which is *[The Dragon and the George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_and_the_George)*.  Thank you all for your help! Now I can read them again :)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some similarities to Christopher Stasheff's The Warlock Unlocked, the third book in his Warlock series. Him and his family are transported to another universe, where magic actually works. Rod Gallowglass, continuously denies he is a warlock, but in this novel, actually becomes one. I believe there is a subplot of him looking for his wife. However, he's not broke and was originally sent to the planet where the 1st. book takes place as an investigator. 
             [image]

Answer (score -3):

I think this is almost certainly not what you are looking for, but it sounds vaguely similar to [The Magicians](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6101718-the-magicians) by Lev Grossman, which I heartily recommend in any case.

Comment: I enjoyed reading The Magicians, but there was no magical land, no scientific experiments were involved and the main protaganist wasn't married.

Comment: Well I did say it is almost certainly not what she is looking for. You never know how much she's misremembering though.

Don't they go to a magical land at some point? It's been a while since I read it...